# Custom Cells Returning Blank in TableView Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

So I am currently trying to populate a tableview with custom cells based on an API call. After I get the data to populate with, I reload the tableview. It has the data based on how many cells it has, but each one is blank. I've looked over some similar problems people had, but can't seem to find the fix. Any help would be great, thank you!

I call my API and collect the data I need. Then I reload the tableview.

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var typeSwitch: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UITextField!
var timeoutTracker = 0
var items: [String] = []
var count = 1
func searchCall() {
    Alamofire.request("http://www.plex.dev/api/search/" + type + "/" + searchBar.text!).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        if response.response == nil {
            self.timeoutTracker = self.timeoutTracker + 1
            if self.timeoutTracker == 5 {
                self.timeoutTracker = 0
                self.popUp()
            }
            else {
                sleep(2)
                self.searchCall()
            }
        }
        if let json = response.result.value {
            let jsonTest = JSON(json)
            for x in jsonTest["results"] {
                if let title = x.1["title"].string {
                    self.items.append(title)
                    self.tableView.delegate = self
                    self.tableView.dataSource = self
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    return self.items.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! MovieCell
    cell.movieTitle?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.moviePoster?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "avatar.png")
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

Here is the custom Cell Class

```
import UIKit

class MovieCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var moviePoster: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var movieTitle: UILabel!
    @IBAction func addMovie(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    }

}
```

Here is my storyboard:
[image]

And here is my blank tableview:
[image]

I hope it isn't something obvious, but thanks for the help either way!

EDIT: changing my identifier to something other than "cell" seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the searchCall() anywhere? 
Also would suggest you to declare

```
 tableView.delegate = self
 tableView.dataSource = self
```

in viewDidLoad() of the SearchViewController and add the delegates and datasource of the UITableView as an extension to SearchViewController (it is a better code practice)

EDIT: After looking again at your cellForRowAt: try and replace your code with the following

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MovieCell
```

and not use self.tableView here

EDIT 2: Sometimes using the default cell identifier 'cell' can cause some problems, so better to use a different one such as 'movieCell'

Comment: I am calling it and I also have both of those in viewdidload(). I had just added that again in case that was the issue for some reason but it didnt change anything.

Comment: try to remove them from the function and keep the only in viewDidLoad(). Your datasource code seems to be alright. You should maybe add some breaking points in your code and see if the tableView get's refreshed after you load all the data it needs and also use NSLog to check items[indexPath.row] to see if it actually has a value

Comment: I added in your edit and that didn't seem to change anything. I checked and the tableview functions are getting called with every increment of the for loop

Comment: last thing I can think about is that somehow the cell from the storyboard is not properly connected somehow ... try to change the cell identifier to something else than 'cell' and check to see that everything is set up in the right way

Comment: Wow that was it! Thanks a ton I never would have thought I needed a different Identifier. Would you please edit your answer to contain that in case someone else runs into this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are registering a class or nib with your table view, but when you use prototype cells you should not do this. Also, you should use the more modern `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String , for indexPath: IndexPath)`. Also, I would resist the temptation to ever call `sleep`.

Comment: What should I be doing in place of registering my table view? And what would you recommend in place of sleep? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Prototype cells are registered automatically. Why are you calling sleep in the first place? `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String)` returns an optional. `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String , for indexPath: IndexPath)` is guaranteed to return an initialized cell. `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String , for indexPath: IndexPath)` was introduced in 2012 it is recommended that you use that. `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String)` is archaic.

Answer (score -1):

Did you give the class to the cell and connect the outlets in cell

Comment: No, but I know the reload is working. When I run it, my tableview functions get called for each new piece of data. It just does not show up.